# DataTables error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to populate a table using DataTables:

```
<table id="diTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

An my jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#diTable').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: '/ajax/get/full',
            dataSrc: 'fields'
        },
        columns: [
            {data: 'name'},
            {data: 'age'}
        ]
   });
});
```

I get the tables layout done by Datatables, but the data is not loaded. I tried to get my data via simple ajax. My data looks like:

```
[
{"pk": 1, "fields": {"name": "Ravil", "age": 30}}, 
{"pk": 2, "fields": {"name": "Rdreis", "age": 50}}, 
{"pk": 3, "fields": {"name": "Gramani", "age": 20}}, 
{"pk": 4, "fields": {"name": "Menthrali", "age": 23}}
]
```

Where am I wrong?

*Note: I am using jQuery 1.11.3 and DataTables 1.10*

Answer (score 1):

you can try it

```
$('#diTable').DataTable({
        "aaData": dataz,
        "aoColumns": [
          { "mDataProp": "fields.name" },
          { "mDataProp": "fields.age" },
        ]
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jho2dths/